# Using faker with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, faker

I have installed faker:

```
pip install faker

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
from faker import Faker

f = Faker()
```

Then I have a class:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
     name_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('input_1')
     name_field.send_keys('f.name()')
```

The driver adds the name f.name() in the input box instead of a random name

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put `f.name()` into quotes:

```
name_field.send_keys(f.name())
```

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from faker import Faker

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')

f = Faker()

field = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
field.send_keys(f.name())
```

Results into:

[image]